# VS 2013 does not recognize some objects on razor cshtml

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, orchardcms-1.7

when I open project in VS 2013, there is some problem with recognize some object on cshtml razor files and intelisence is out. 
[image]
On VS 2012 its everything ok. Its will need some change on web.config or VS settings? Here is web.config:

```
    <configuration>

  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <remove name="host" />
      <remove name="pages" />
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="Orchard.Mvc.ViewEngines.Razor.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
        <add namespace="System.Linq"/>
        <add namespace="System.Collections.Generic"/>
        <add namespace="Orchard.Mvc.Html"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Which version of Orchard are you using? The latest Dev branch has working intellisense in VS2013, older versions like 1.7 do not.

Comment: Its Orchard 1.7.2, I though that is the latest version. I have some 1.7.1 too and same problem. When I open the same projects on VS2012 its ok.

Comment: 1.7.2 is the latest release, 1.x is the dev branch with the latest code. It is something to do with Web config files targeting the correct .net framework I think, not too sure. This thread has some more info I think. http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/468462 I have decided to stick with vs2012 for 1.7.2 development and am doing my messing around with the 1.x branch on 2013 :)

Comment: :) I guess it'll have to do so too. But its somewhat impractical.

Comment: This link solves the problem [orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/468462](http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/468462)

Comment: Thank you, Hazza. Link solves, it required some changes of web.configs.